# "intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains" message upon boot

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualization

I install fresh Ubuntu 14. 04  server under ESXI 5.1.0.
During my installation I did not get any erorrs or strange things.
My problem is when I boot machine at console screen I get messages like

```
[ 6.958104] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0 
[ 7.508153] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[ 8.058695] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[ 8.609932] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
[ 9.163260] intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains found in package 0
```

After that messages I am able to log in and my to me Ubuntu works OK.
I have internet connection I am able to call apt-get update and I am able to login over SSH.

Should I investigate these errors deeply before I continue build my server.
Do I need to react on these Messages or it is ok to run Ubuntu like this.

Comment: The intel_rapl message was driving me crazy. The solution for me was to (sudo) edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `blacklist intel_rapl`. No more messages after reboot.

Comment: odd... i got this on a fresh install under Parallels and the initial boot process doesn't get past seeing this message.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This was a change introduced in [October 2013](https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/10/11/1010) to support Intel RAPL power capping driver in the Linux kernel. This message is non-obstructive, and when it appears it doesn't affect the performance or functionality of the system, since it's only a power management module.

If your virtualization software supports this driver (and the host supports advanced power features) then the message disappears.

You can check the [source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/powercap) of the module to check what it does.

Answer (score 35):

I know in VirtualBox you can enable PAE/NX which will solve "no valid rapl domains found in package" on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I don't know how about ESXI if it supports PAE/NX or not.

[image: Virtual Box Enable PAE/NX]

Comment: I'm on 14.04, with PAE/NX enabled, and still see the message.

Comment: I tried your solution to run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I still see the message but it can boot into Ubuntu.

Comment: Same here. Still saw the message even with PAE/NX enabled. Oh well, no big deal. Just a bit annoying :-)

Comment: Did not work for me.

Comment: Doesn't work for Mint 18.2 running on VirtualBox 5.1.22. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

edit the *.vmx file and set `paevm = "TRUE"` in order to enable [PAE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE) - or blacklist the module:

```
echo 'blacklist intel_rapl' >> /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf
mkinitcpio -p linux
reboot
```

Comment: I don't know what `mkinitcpio` is, but simply adding `blacklist intel_rapl` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` removed that message (note the different filename on my Linux Mint). All I wanted was this rap-whatever to not taint my splashscreen and now it doesn't.

Comment: @user3125367 mkinitcpio is the program you use to re-generate the init image file that accompanies the kernel at boot time. It contains all settings/drivers/whatever else the kernel needs at boot time before the actual filesystem has been mounted.

Answer (score 0):

I got this message and not able to continue to the login screen.
I solved it by entering `Recovery Mode`, then run `fsck`, from the menu option.
It solved my issue, I was able to enter my OS.
I still see this warning message each reboot, but I can enter the OS.

Comment: Most likely unrelated...