# Cannot see Boot Screen on Ubuntu 15.04 running on Virtualbox

Tags: boot, grub2, virtualbox, plymouth

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my laptop. Inside that, On virtualbox i have installed another ubuntu 15.04.
I see the ubuntu logo during the boot on the host but on the guest I see the message

```
ACPI PCC PROBE FAILED. STARTING VERSION 219.
SMBUS BASE ADDRESS UNINITIALIZED
ade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr
no valid ralp domains
```

I have checked /etc/default/grub file. It is exactly the same on both the host and the guest.

Also my plymouth theme is /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth on both the host and the guest Ubuntu.

I want to know the meaning of the lines in the codes and the procedure to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a two-part issue, the first part is

`ACPI PCC PROBE FAILED. STARTING VERSION 219.
SMBUS BASE ADDRESS UNINITIALIZED
ade BIOS or use force_addr=0xaddr`

I am not sure what the cause of this is, but it pops up every time I boot Ubuntu in Virtualbox.  According to this question,  [Boot Error - ACPI PCC Probe Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584248/boot-error-acpi-pcc-probe-failed) the error is harmless.  It is possible to get rid of it by disabling nested paging.

Your second issue, `no valid ralp domains` is in reference to a power management module.  This page ["intel_rapl: no valid rapl domains" message upon boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449574/intel-rapl-no-valid-rapl-domains-message-upon-boot) has some good information about it if you want to know more.

Neither of these messages should prevent your system from booting.  You should still see the boot screen, the messages should only be a slight delay.  Are you unable to boot?  If so, you likely have another issue.

Comment: I am able to boot.After booting ubuntu runs normally. It's just that i want to see Ubuntu logo during booting and not these messages.

Comment: The links you have provided are highly related but unable to solve the problem practically.